# Spartacus 3.2 connect with Auth0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to connect Spartacus 3.2 with Auth0. With below config I am able to successful login from Auth0

```
provideConfig(<AuthConfig>{authentication: {
  OAuthLibConfig: {
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: redirectURL,
  },
  baseUrl: 'https://DomainName',
  client_id: 'clientID',
  loginUrl: '/authorize',
}})
```

Issue is:
How to pass accesstoken bearer token (Authorization) and idtoken in headers that is from Auth0? in every page call.
Can I please know how to solve this?